# Does Kotlin have it's own function for rounding up when a number is greater than zero, but rounding down when a number is less than zero?

Tags: kotlin, rounding, built-in

Prepended: I just found a similar question about Java. This question is the exact same as that except about Kotlin. This means I would prefer not referencing any Java code and am wondering about native Kotlin.

Is there a function that always rounds up, but relative to zero. Essentially a rounding function that will always round *away* from zero. A cousin of ceil if you will. For example...

```
\\ Ceil does this
someRoundFun(0.04)
1
\\ And floor does this
someRoundFun(-0.04)
1
```

I want to know if there is a built-in function that reproduces this in Kotlin. I know how to program one myself, I just want to know if there is a built-in (for elegance). It might look something like this.

```
fun round(num: Double) == if (num > 0) ceil(num) else floor(num)
```

Comment: If there were, it would be in `kotlin.math`, so no. There's the opposite of what you described: `truncate()`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Wouldn't `-truncate(-num)` give exactly the same result as `truncate(num)`? I'm not seeing how it would produce round-away-from-zero semantics.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Don't know what I was thinking there, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin has [ceil](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/ceil.html) in it's kotlin.math library, but it rounds to the next whole number.

kotlin.math is in kotlin-stdlib so I'd assume it fits your requirement of native Kotlin.

Comment: I knew about ceil already. I assume it would round to 0 though. `ceil(-0.04)` would equal 0, yes? This is _not_ what I want.

Comment: Yeah, I found a quote from the documentation. "Rounds the given value x to an integer towards positive infinity." I would also like it to round towards negative infinity if the value is negative.

Comment: There is a function "fun Double.withSign(sign: Double): Double" so you can do something like: ceil(num.absoluteValue).withSign(num), but it looks a bit clunky.